# EF Core : get random values ​from database

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a parent table and a child table,I want to randomly receive 3 values ​​from each print ID in the child table and display them on the site.

Parent table:

```
Id       Name
---------------
1        Red
2        Blue 
3        Green
```

Child Table

```
Id   ColorId   Name
-----------------------
1       1      RedOne 
2       1      RedTwo
3       1      RedThree
4       2      BlueOne
5       2      BlueTwo
6       2      BlueThree
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show classes and what is Print ID?

Comment: try this Random rand = new Random();
 int toSkip = rand.Next(0, childTableData.Count());
data.Skip(toSkip).Take(3).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try as below:

```
Controller:
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var colors =await  _context.Color.Include(x => x.colorChildren.OrderBy(y => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3).OrderBy(y=>y.Id)).ToListAsync();
            //make a check before return View
             ....
            return  View(colors);
                         
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Color>





<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Colors
            </th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    ChildColor
            </td>
                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
                @foreach (var child in item.colorChildren)
                {

                    <td>
                        @child.Name
                    </td>


                }
        </tr>
            
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Every time I refresh the page, diffrent childcolors would be displayed:
[image]